# Rails server takes a long time to start up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was working on a Rails project, but while I wasn't paying attention my computer battery died while the rails server was still running.

Now when I type `rails s`, the rails server takes a very very long time to start up. I timed it at about 40 seconds. It did not take this long before.

I tried looking up other answers, but nothing really worked.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

I'm running a 2010 Macbook Pro, Rails 4.2.0

Comment: So the computer restarted? I don't know of anything that could be doing this :\ Restart it a couple of more times... Re install ruby... I think macs have `strace` or can possibly install it, try using that to look for anything unusual with files being opened, or locks taking time to unlock.

Comment: My computer completely shut off, but then I charged it and turned in back on and noticed that running `rails s` took forever. I'll go ahead and restart my computer again and see if there is any change.

Comment: Oh, it's a mac and they go into hibernate though right? Look around at the processes hanging around `ps aux | grep -i -e rails -e ruby`

Comment: Webrick is slow consider using another server. I will suggest `thin` or `pow` https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/web_servers

Comment: @JacobMinshall 

 `admin            5256   0.0  0.0  2432772    636 s000  S+    2:12AM   0:00.00 grep -i -e rails -e ruby`
I ran it a few more times and the numbers are changing(to be honest, I don't know what they all mean).

`admin            5274   0.0  0.0  2442588      0 s000  R+    2:12AM   0:00.00 grep -i -e rails -e ruby`
It changes everytime I run it

Comment: That's just grep finding itself. So it's not a process laying around. :\

Comment: @JacobMinshall, well this is gonna sound stupid. this was my 3rd time restarting my computer after my battery died, and it restarts way faster now. I'd say ~10 seconds or less. thanks for helping!

Comment: Not only for `rails s` all rails command takes so longs. `rails c`, `rails db:setup` etc., After restarting my system, it runs in a few(5-10) seconds.

Answer (score -1):

You can turn eager_loading and cache_control false and then it will take few seconds to start server

1. go to development.rb file
2. "config.cache_classes" and "config.eager_load" turn to false

Note:
  By turning cache_control to false will gradually increase server boot up time (**in development environment**) as you don't need to restart webserver when you make changes in code.
  By turning eager_load to false will increase server boot up time from 2 minutes to 10 seconds but can cause inconsistency so use it wisely.